# php uniqid() error

Tags: php, uniqueidentifier

I actually want to generate random password using PHP uniqid() function

```
$randomPassword = uniqid();
```

But doing this gives me an error:-

```
Unknown column '4f74456589d51' in 'field list'
```

What is the reason?

I am inserting this value in my database:-

```
$SQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO cust (password) VALUES (%s)", myFunction($randomPassword, "text"));
```

Comment: That is sql error . When this error occurs ? Write your sql query

Comment: are you saving this to a mysql database?

Comment: You're putting this into sql query without quoting... Use quotes around $randomPassword in your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$SQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO cust (password) VALUES ('%s')", GetSQLValueString($randomPassword, "text"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$SQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO cust (password) VALUES ('%s')", myFunction($randomPassword, "text"));
```

you forgot the ' ' around the %s